# Is this static method thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, static

I have below classes:

```
public static class MetadataManager
{
    // assume that it is thread safe
    public static List<Field> FieldRegistry { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public static class FieldDataValidationManager
{
    public static bool Validate(int fieldID)
    {
        return MetadataManager.FieldRegistry.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == fieldID).ID > 1;
    }

    public static bool Validate(Field field)
    {
        return fieldID.ID > 1;
    }
}
```

Now, 
User1 and User2 is calling static method at the same time, is there any problem regarding concurrency?

```
FieldDataValidationManager.Validate(111)
```

or 
User1 is executing 
`FieldDataValidationManager.Validate(field1)` and User2 is executing `FieldDataValidationManager.Validate(field2)`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, your code is thread-safe, since your code is just reading from the list. Being static or not doesn't matter at all.

If there would be write actions on the `List<T>`, you would have possible concurrency problems. Then you should use `ConcurrentBag<T>` or other thread-safe collection types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no concurrency problem as long as you don't change the content of the `FieldRegistry` list.
But you did not show where you fill that list. So if your actual code *does insert or remove entries* to that list while other threads are calling `Validate` there will be problems (a [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1) as suggested by Patrick Hofman may be a good alternative for that).

---

But what are you actually trying to do here:

```
public static bool Validate(int fieldID)
{
    return MetadataManager.FieldRegistry.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == fieldID).ID > 1;
}
```

So it seems your `fieldID` is valid if there is already an entry with that `ID` *and* the `ID` is greater than `1`?
OK, but your method will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the `fieldID` is not already contained in your list. So you better change that method to something like this:

```
public static bool Validate(int fieldID)
{        
    return 
        MetadataManager.FieldRegistry.Any(f => f.ID == fieldID) &&
        fieldID > 1;
}
```

Comment: Dear Rene. I agree with you but it is just for example.